# is it ok to pay off a larger transaction early BEFORE it posts or extracts it from the account?

Tags: credit

to be on the safe side..is it ok to pay off a larger transaction early BEFORE it posts or extracts it from the account?
i have a good score and this cc is the only one that affects it. it is a personal cc..

Comment: I regularly make payments like that.  Chase (my bank) used to only allow payments up to the posted balance, but now they take pending charges into account, too.

Comment: “To be on the safe side” ? As far as credit reports are concerned, it’s worth noting what time of the cycle the card reports to the credit bureaus and just pay the full balance before that day.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an extra payment to a credit card in any amount at any time. If it exceeds the current balance you owe, then your balance will go negative (meaning the card company owes *you* money). In your scenario, the balance would then revert to its previous level once the purchase transaction posts.

This is a way to prevent a purchase from even temporarily increasing your balance owed (credit utilization). However, this is typically not necessary because utilization is [reported](https://www.creditkarma.com/credit-cards/i/credit-card-companies-report-credit-bureaus) to credit bureaus monthly on your statement closing date. As long as you make a payment by that date, you can prevent your reported utilization from increasing.